# Which one of you is Jesus?

Tags: knowledge

In the quest for finding Jesus, five people remain.

The first subject can summon bears.
The second subject can stop waves.
The third subject can summon zombies.
The fourth subject can tear off limbs.
The fifth subject can turn their staff into a snake.

Which one is Jesus?

Comment: my dad's name is levon, does that count

Comment: Is this a trick question? Jesus could do all of these things. Only the second is mentioned in the Bible, though.

Comment: I know a Jesus from Mexico that can tear off limbs. does that count?

Comment: @question_asker No.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uh....

> The 2nd one. Each of these is a miracle in the bible and only the 2nd one is attributed to Jesus.

The first subject can summon bears.

> Elisha

The second subject can stop waves.

> Jesus

The third subject can summon zombies.

> Ezekiel. He brought back a bunch of bones to life.

The fourth subject can tear off limbs.

> Samson

The fifth subject can turn their staff into a snake.

> Moses

Answer (score 7):

Putting aside the fact that Jesus wouldn't likely do miracles on demand<sup>*</sup>, the only miracle listed that is unique to Jesus in the Bible is:

> And he awoke and rebuked the wind and said to the sea, “Peace! Be still!” And the wind ceased, and there was a great calm.—Mark 4:39 ([ESV](http://biblehub.com/esv/mark/4.htm))

---

* Reference:

> And the Pharisees and Sadducees came, and to test him they asked him to show them a sign from heaven. He answered them, “When it is evening, you say, ‘It will be fair weather, for the sky is red.’ And in the morning, ‘It will be stormy today, for the sky is red and threatening.’ You know how to interpret the appearance of the sky, but you cannot interpret the signs of the times. An evil and adulterous generation seeks for a sign, but no sign will be given to it except the sign of Jonah.” So he left them and departed.—Matthew 16:1-4 ([ESV](http://biblehub.com/esv/matthew/16.htm))

Answer (score 5):

This seems too literal-minded, but:

> Either the second or the third is Jesus, probably the second; these are all somewhat well-known stories from the Bible. (Though I'm in some doubt about a couple of them, as you will see below.)

The first subject can summon bears.

> This one is Elisha.

The second subject can stop waves.

> This one might be Jesus (the "calming of the storm" story) but I wonder whether there are other good candidates. I can't think of any, though.

The third subject can summon zombies.

> This one might be Jesus (resurrection of Lazarus; maybe also the bit in Matthew's gospel about people emerging from their tombs at Jesus's resurrection). There are a few other resurrection stories in the Bible, but those two are much more zombie-like than any of the others. The other, not very convincing, candidates here are: Elijah, Elisha, St Peter, and St Paul. ... Aha, in another answer LCIII offers Ezekiel and his dry bones, which is actually pretty convincing.

The fourth subject can tear off limbs.

> Don't know about this one. (A couple of people have suggested Samson, but he isn't exactly described as tearing off limbs. He does tear a lion apart "as if it were a young goat", but I'm not convinced that's the same.) In any case, nothing of this kind is attributed to Jesus.

The fifth subject can turn their staff into a snake.

> This one is Moses.

[I've edited this a few times; bear that in mind if any comments don't seem to make sense.]

Comment: 'stopping waves' might be referring to the splitting of the Red Sea by Moses... and just for the sake of accuracy Aaron was the one with the staff and snake in front of Pharoah (Exodus 7:10)

Comment: I was thinking along exactly the same lines.   and came up with the same answers for 1 and 5.

Comment: If this is correct/the right way to solve it, this wasn't really even a puzzle in the first place :/

Comment: Ben, I hope not because "stopping waves" doesn't really have much to do with that story, does it? (I wonder about sound waves or light waves...)

Comment: Gordon, I agree which is why I'm hoping the whole approach is way too literal-minded. I'm encouraged by my inability to think of a good candidate for #4.

Comment: Also, for 3, google the witch of endor. (And stick to bible sites, not Star Wars)

Comment: Chris: ghost not zombie, surely?

Comment: Maybe #4 is a reference to Samson?  He does tear a lion apart.

Comment: Could the fourth possibly be a reference to the Eucharist?

Comment: Mark, maybe (though "can tear off limbs" seems a rather strange way to describe that). Tonkleton, that's an ingenious idea but I really don't think so.